# 2 Dimensional Elastic Collisions final speed increases?

Tags: performance, simulation, physics, collision

Problem in short: 
I have two moving balls in a 2d space which collide so there will be a velocity before impact v1i v2i and a velocity after impact v1f v2f, which are, of course, represented by vectors. Is it normal that the sum of the norm of the velocity of the balls isn't conserved but increases? 
So norm(v1i) + norm(v2i) < norm(v1f) + norm(v2f).

I thought it should be impossibile since that means that the balls gained velocity out of nowhere but I may be missing something and maybe the sum of the norm isn't coserved in this kind of impacts.

Long version:
known data: velocity vectors of the two balls i and j (sorry if the notation is a bit confusing) before impact vi, vj, position vectors of the center of the two balls pi, pj, radius and mass of both balls which are identical r, m.

This are two ways to calculate the final velocity of the two balls:

```
                %velocity vectors
                vi=[vix; viy];
                vj=[vjx; vjy];

                %position(center) of the balls 
                pi=[xi; yi];
                pj=[xj; yj];

                %normal vector in the point of impact
                n = pi - pj;

                %normal unit vector in the point of impact
                un=n/norm(n);

                %tangent unit vector in the point of impact
                ut=[-un(2); un(1)];

                %project velocity in the normal and tangent directions using dot product
                vin=dot(un,vi);
                vit=dot(ut,vi);
                vjn=dot(un,vj);
                vjt=dot(ut,vj);

                %final normal velocity is calculated combining conservation
                %of momentum and kinetic energy in only the normal dimension
                vinf=vjn;
                vjnf=vin;

                %final tangent velocity remains the same
                vitf=vit;
                vjtf=vjt;

                %final velocity is the sum of the tan e norm components
                vif=vinf*un + vitf*ut;
                vjf=vjnf*un + vjtf*ut;

                if norm(vi)+norm(vj) < norm(vif)+norm(vjf)
                   print("Energy violation")


                %There was also a much faster way to calculate the final
                %velocity: vif=(vi-(dot(vi-vj,n)/(norm(n)^2))*(n));
                %but this way is more easy to understand. Both give the same 
                % result.
```

Here is a numeric example:

vi =
    4.0422
    0.2023

vj =
   -0.5104
    0.2552

n =
   -4.9436
   -2.8675

vif =
    0.6587
   -1.7603

vjf =
    2.6864
    2.1095

norm(vi)+norm(vj) =  4.6179

norm(vif)+norm(vjf) =  5.2951

Comment: What are `pi` and `pj`?

Comment: `final normal velocity is calculated combining conservation of momentum and kinetic energy in only the normal dimension` - why only in the normal dimension? The total momentum and KE should be preserved.

Comment: @ysap pi and pj are two vectors with the coordinate x and y of the center of ball i and ball j so for example pi = [xi yi] and pj = [xj yj]

Comment: @ysap also, since tangent velocity is the same I can use the two laws only in the normal direction to simplyfied the math

Comment: Yeah I realized that there was no instruction in the code about pi and pj thanks for pointing it out I will edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine help me got the answer, I simply was missing to square the norm of the velocity vectors, that was a stupid mistake, my bad. So the sum of the norm isn't in fact conserved but the sum of the squared norm is.

Comment: Momentum is conserved, not velocity. Consider a very small body at rest colliding with a large at high velocity. The large body will basically keep its velocity while the very small will gain.